# C# - Separate UI from business code

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I want to know what's the best practice for the following case :

I'm developing an application that need to be used on three different screen size : 240x320 ; 800x600 ; 1280x1024 (and only these three) in different languages (using localization).

So what I've done is to create a library by screen size, each implementing an interface defined in the project that calls these screens.

First question is, all my resources files are duplicated and that is many files to keep up to date (or with duplicate labels). Is there a simple way to change this?

Second question is, am I using the good approach or exists it a better way to do what I'm trying to do? By applying a design pattern maybe?

---

### Sample code

The caller code :

```
    public int X { get { return 800; } }
    public int Y { get { return 600; } }

    public interface IScreenForm
    {
        Form FormComponent { get; }
    }

    public interface IFormA : IScreenForm
    {
        TextBox UserTextBox { get; } // For use
    }

    public void LoadForm<T>()
        where T:IScreenForm
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(typeof(T).Name + " is not an interface");
        }

        Assembly screenAssembly;
        string screenResolutionDll = string.Format("{0}_{1}_screens.dll", this.X, this.Y);

        screenAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(screenResolutionDll);

        Type formType = screenAssembly.GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.Name == typeof(T).Name).Count() > 0);

        if (formType != null)
        {
            Form form = (Form)formType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null);
            if (form != null)
            {
                form.Show();
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Form doesn't provide a new() ctor");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Any form doesn't implement the interface : " + typeof(T).Name);
        }
    }
```

Screen DLL :

```
public partial class MyFirstForm : Form, caller.IFormA
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /* caller.IFormA interface implementation */
}
```

Comment: what is that? WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Comment: Is screensize the only difference?

Comment: Except that the smallest screen size is compiler under Compact Framework and other under .NET Framework, their is no difference

Comment: Looks like you're trying todo an Model View Presenter pattern.

Comment: This is what most Android apps do routinely.  Look inside an apk file (just rename and unzip it).  The res directory (and subdirs) mostly consists of different sizes of graphics.

Comment: 6 years later? Thanks 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arnaud, from my own experience, from reading, and from talking to experienced developers: When it comes to supporting multiple screen sizes and with localization, there are no magic bullets.  For localization put all your strings in resource files, or even in data files.

As far as the screen sizes, I would not try to be too clever.  Yes, make sure that none of your business / non-GUI logic gets duplicated, but duplicating resource files, forms, etc - I would not worry about it.  Some GUI frameworks like Qt and GTK auto-resize and auto-position GUI-widgets (e.g. Qt has 'spacer' widgets).  It works OK most of the time, however I still prefer explicit control.  With GUI programming, there are often unexpected glitches, having three independent sets of GUI components will allow you to address them, should they arise.  Some example sources of problems:
1) Font sizing. 
2) Windows accessibility settings.
3) Some national languages have longer average words than others, the long words have trouble fitting in the real estate available.

If I were in your shoes, I would look for example how browsers handle this (e.g. mobile vs. desktop version) and I would try to find some practical advice on the Web (like here at SO).  I doubt that books on design patterns will help much with this. Disclaimer: I am a design-pattern skeptic.

Comment: I'll follow your advice mister. But rene has the good answer, what I'm tying to do is a MVP design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to advice without getting the whole picture but for some tips that might by handy read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648753.aspx

about the SmartClient software Factory.

It comes with architecural guidance and solutions for issue you often see in this kind of apps